# Fishpig Magento Wordpress Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, magento, post

I'm using fishpig's wordpress integration for magento plugin to show contents of my wordpress within my magento site. I'm trying to add infinite scroll to my magento theme, but am not sure how to proceed. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Did you find any solution?